# How to transform one grid to another using only bootstrap tools?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image]

I need to transform the grid that you see above to grid that you see below.
For above I use next grid:

```
<div className="row">
    <div className="col-md-6">100</div>
    <div className="col-md-6">100</div>
    <div className="col-md-6">100</div>
    <div className="col-md-6">100</div>
    <div className="col-md-6">100</div>
    <div className="col-md-6">100</div>
  </div>
```

For just 2 column we can replace col-md-2 to col-md-6 but I have more complex order

Comment: The [re-ordering](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#reordering) isn't tough using bootstrap grid, but breaking into new lines etc will require changing the html structure as well as just the classes. Not a very ideal way to handle whatever you're aiming for a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. You can use Bootstrap flexbox [order utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/#order).

`.col-6` class will give you 2-column layout until `md` breakpoint. After that, `.col-md-2` class will give you 6-column layout.

#### HTML

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 order-md-6">
        6
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 order-md-2">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 order-md-1">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 order-md-4">
        4
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 order-md-3">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2 order-md-5">
        5
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Screenshots

[image]

[image]

#### Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/0f2qowre/5/